# Laravel job new property assigned in constructor not showing in handle method

Tags: php, laravel

In a Laravel job class, whose code is below as an illustration.
I want to assign a property (reserve not a column on db) to my object if a condition is met. The issue is that I can't see that property outside the constructor. Please what am I doing wrong?

```
class SomeJob implements ShouldQueue
{   
  private $length = 300;
  private $width;
  private $area;

  public function __construct()
  {
    $areas = Area::where('length', $this->length)->get()->each(function($area) {
     if($area->length === 300) {
       $area->reserve = ($area->length + 400);
     }
   });

   $this->area = $areas;
   // *log has $area
  }
  
  public function handle()
  {
   $area = $this->area;

   logger($area);
   // *log does not have $area
  }

}
```

Comment: I know I can move the queries to the handle method, and that would be fine, but I'm wondering why this is not working.

Comment: I would try making those properties public or at least protected.

Comment: when you create Job laravel srialize it and create record in jobs table. then worker get this record and deserialize it into initial instance. most likely something is not properly work with serialization/deserialization for Area class

Answer (score 0):

The Solution does not make sense but making the area property public instead of private seems to work.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

To access any property within a method, you have to explicitly call that method,  e.g `$sj = new someJob(); $sj->handle()`; . "Var dumping" a class reveals its property and depending on the environment and visibility some properties may or may not be visible. When a class is instantiated, the constructor is called first automatically, and that is why you could 'log' and see your class property. Within the hood, Laravel calls the handle method when running the job class, but if you're testing it manually you have to do that yourself.

Comment: Here it is @VijayRana.

Answer (score 0):

I think the properties have to be `protected` instead of `private`.

Answer (score -1):

You need to define the properties outside of the `__construct()` function. Currently those variables are scoped to only be available within the `__construct()` closure.

```php
class SomeJob implements ShouldQueue
{   
     protected $length;
     protected $width;
     protected $area;

     public function __construct()
     {
         //...
```

Comment: it is still within the class I'm using it. but it's only available in the constructor and not the handle method as illustrated. changing the visibility didn't help.

Comment: You need to move them outside of `__construct()`

Comment: sure that would work. But just curious why this doesn't.

Comment: Because you aren’t defining properties on the class. The scope is within the function.

Comment: It was actually meant to be outside the constructor. I didn't type that properly.

Comment: @Lekia did you find any solution?

Comment: Check my answer above @VijayRana .